# GAE subdomain and DNS

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain

I have a situation where my domain is on go daddy, my web server on 1and1 and I would like a subdomain to point to my app engine.

I put setup my DNS so my domain name point to my site on my webserver, however I'm having some issues configuring my DNS and GAE to get my subdomain to point and to my app.

Any idea or suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a question for GoDaddy.  They have good tech support and actually answer the phone.  Call them.  If you can set up your subdomain to point to different records, then it would work on GAE's end.  But, I don't think you can do this.  Call them to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the fix.

I had to validate my domain name as `<subdomain>.<domain>` (That's the tricky part)
I added the provided test TXT rule with my subdomain as target instead of @.

Once that's done, GAE will provide a list of records to setup for the subdomain and instead of @, I added my subdomain everywhere and www. for the last CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup specific subdomain on App Engine by following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#using_subdomains)